# create trigger which will remove numbers from string

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've created function which removes numbers from string

```
create function RemoveNumber(@inp nvarchar(50))
returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
declare @out varchar(50)
if (@inp is NOT NULL)
begin
    set @out = ''
    while (@inp <> '')
    begin
        if (@inp like '[0-9]%')
            set @out = @out + substring(@in, 1, 1)
        set @inp = substring(@inp, 2, len(@in) - 1)
    end
end
return(@out)
end
```

Then I wanted to use it inside the trigger

```
create trigger ut_RemoverName
on Worker
for insert
as
update Worker
set name = ut_RemoveNumber(name)
```

It doesn't see the function. But how to create loop from RemoveNumber inside the trigger?(Field `name` - `nvarchar(10)`)

Comment: I think you want set "set name = ut_RemoveNumber(name)" to be "set name = RemoveNumber(name)"

Comment: Depending on the RDMS you may also need a user qualification e.g. `dbo.RemoveNumber(name)`

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: "how to create loop ..." is almost always the wrong question to ask with SQL - you should be looking for a way to apply whatever actions you want to a set as a whole.

Comment: oh. my bad - I forgot to mention ds - sql server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need this

```
create trigger ut_RemoverName on Worker
for insert
as
UPDATE w
SET Name = dbo.RemoveNumber(i.name)
FROM Worker w JOIN inserted i ON w.Id = i.Id
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d554/2/1)